# Left JOIN issuedevices AS sm ON sd.DeviceID = sm.DeviceID' at line 1

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, mariadb

I want to take data from two tables.

Table one `deviceadd` has these columns

```
DeviceID (primary key), DeviceName, SerialNumber, ModelNumber, Make
```

and the other table `issuedevices` has these columns:

```
Device_ID (Unique), Employee_id, Employee_Name, Employee_Ext, Issue_Date
```

I get this error:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
>   version for the right syntax to use near 'Left JOIN issuedevices AS sm
>   ON sd.DeviceID = sm.DeviceID' at line 1

```
PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("Selectsd.DeviceID,sd.DeviceName,sd.SerialNumber,sd.ModelNumber,sd.Make,sm.DeviceID,sm.Employee_Name,sm.Employee_Ext,sm.Issue_Date From deviceadd AS sd,Left JOIN issuedevices AS sm ON sd.DeviceID = sm.DeviceID");

        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();

        ResultSetMetaData rsmd=rs.getMetaData();
        int cols=rsmd.getColumnCount();
        column=new String[cols];
        for(int i=1;i<=cols;i++)
        {
            column[i-1]=rsmd.getColumnName(i);
        }

        rs.last();
        int rows=rs.getRow();
        rs.beforeFirst();

        data=new String[rows][cols];
        int count=0;
        while(rs.next()){
            for(int i=1;i<=cols;i++)
            {
                data[count][i-1]=rs.getString(i);
            }
            count++;
        }
        con.close();
    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}

    table = new JTable(data,column);
    JScrollPane sp=new JScrollPane(table);

    contentPane.add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: Remove the comma after `AS sd,`

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is that there is no space here:

```
Selectsd.DeviceID
```

It should be

```
Select sd.DeviceID
```

Also, there shouldn't be a comma here:

```
sd,Left JOIN
```

Comment: I have given space in code instead of that getting error

Comment: "Select sd.DeviceID,sd.DeviceName,sd.SerialNumber,sd.ModelNumber,sd.Make,sm.DeviceID,sm.Employee_Name,sm.Employee_Ext,sm.Issue_Date From deviceadd AS sd,Left JOIN issuedevices AS sm ON sd.DeviceID = sm.DeviceID"

Comment: After removing comma now getting following error >>java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'sm.DeviceID' in 'field list'

Comment: @ user10898341 thanku very much for your reply I have solved the issue sd,Left JOIN. And another new I was getting because I was giving wrong column name